# Can you restrict which OSM tags are returned by Overpass API?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I've been reading up on Overpass syntax and I think I get the basics. For example, let's say I want to get the IDs and coordinates of every town in Andorra that OSM has a record of:

http://overpass.osm.rambler.ru/cgi/interpreter?data=[out:json];area[%22ISO3166-1%22=%22AD%22][admin_level=2];(node[%22place%22=%22town%22](area););out%20ids%20center;

This is great for keeping the data stream light -- say, if you're targeting smartphones and are trying to be conscious of data plan costs.

Now, what if I just want to get the "name" tag of each of these towns in addition to the ID and center? I know how to get *all* of the tags -- just add " tags" right before the final semicolon -- but that gives me a whole bunch of tags I don't want and a bloaty data stream.

Does anyone know whether/how one can selectively include tags in the Overpass output stream?

That is, not filtering nodes by tag but rather filtering tags by tag name.

Comment: Since v0.7.54 https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/versions#Overpass_API_v0.7.54 [Restrict tag lists of objects](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/new) As it `converts` elements, each type appears to have to be listed separately: [bbox:{{bbox}}]; node[amenity=restaurant]; convert node name=t["name"],cuisine=t["cuisine"]; out; way[amenity=restaurant]; convert way name=t["name"],cuisine=t["cuisine"]; out; rel[amenity=restaurant]; convert rel name=t["name"],cuisine=t["cuisine"]; out; is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159847)

Comment: @aldo_tapia I was answering a question. In addendum to that I was querying whether there was a better solution.
Do you have the required knowledge to provide a better solution for others to use?

Comment: Please do not ask questions in Answers. You can *state* that you're looking for a way to further simplify, but if you start asking questions it looks like an "I have this problem too" situation and your answer may be deleted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159847)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily achieve this via CSV output. Read more about it in the Overpass QL documentation.

```
[out:csv(::id, ::lat, ::lon, name)];
area["ISO3166-1"="AD"][admin_level=2];
node[place=town](area);
out center;
```

Try it out: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/qag

Comment: Thanks, @mmd! This works. I would certainly prefer working with JSON over CSV, but I didn't mention that in the prompt. Do you know if there's currently any way to do this and have Overpass output JSON?

Comment: I thought about Json as well, but the approach via convert doesn't support geometry yet and without center point your query result is probably not that useful. This will be available in a future release only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `convert` method to produce your output. From the Ovepass QL documentation:

> After that, an arbitrary number of tags can be set. In addition, it can be specified to copy all keys from the originating object. In this case, it is also possible to selectively suppress some tags.

Example from their home page:

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];

node[start_date]; // find all nodes in current bounding box with start_date tag

convert elem     // convert nodes from inputset to <elem> 
    ::id = id(), // keeping the node id value
      original_date = t[start_date], // value as found in start_date tag
    normalized_date = date(t[start_date]), // start_date converted to numeric value
    is_date = is_date(t[start_date]);     // is start_date a recognized date?

out;
```